# How do I get a quoted text in an element

Tags: selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get the `at Broadway Pilates` from the element below. I'm using `BeautifulSoup`.

```html
<span data-component="LocalizableMessage"> Essential Reformer </span> “at Broadway Pilates”
```

My current code is:

```py
try:
    studio_name = classses_soup.find(
        'span', {'data-component': 'LocalizableMessage'}).text
```

My code only gets the first part `Essential Reformer`. What do i need to do to get the second part `at Broadway Pilates`?

Preferably (but not essential) just `Broadway Pilates`, so without the `at`.

Thank you!!

Comment: Can you please share the html of the span that contains the text you mentioned above.

Comment: I've corrected the format of your question, kindly take a look on [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thank you so much for the corrections. I'm still very new to stackoverflow. I will read through the link you provided. The html to the span is:  https://classpass.com/classes/broadway-pilates-london#tabs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<span data-component="LocalizableMessage"> Essential Reformer </span> “at Broadway Pilates” """

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

for item in soup.findAll("span", {'data-component': 'LocalizableMessage'}):
    print(item.next_sibling.string.strip()[4:-1])
```

Output:

```
Broadway Pilates
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I will try it and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Thank you for this. I made some tweaks to it to get it to work for my goal.